# escape character for $ in sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I got this error `Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 2 near command '1'` when I run the `sqlcmd` for a script. When I check the script I found that

```
INSERT INTO ABC.TableA(Name, Descr) VALUES ('Payment', N'$(162.66)')
```

So when I check online, some variables are like `$(xxxx)` for sqlcmd.
How can I solve the issue? I'm using Microsoft SQL.
Thank you.

Comment: Tried using escape character like '\$'? Because $ is considered as variable replacement while executing sqlcmd

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, Thanks for the answer. I tried to find about the escape character for sqlcmd and found this link http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php but $ is not in the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no escape character, and yes, this is stupid. Either turn off variable substitution with the `-x` option if you're not using variables to begin with, or break up the expression so it no longer parses as a variable substitution:

```
INSERT INTO ABC.TableA(Name, Descr) VALUES ('Payment', N'$' + N'(162.66)')
```

Take care that the result is still of the correct type, where required.

In the rare case where even this is not possible (because a string literal is required and expressions are not permitted) you have to join them rather than beat them, and set a variable to the desired value:

```
:setvar descr $(1.2)
INSERT INTO ABC.TableA(Name, Descr) VALUES ('Payment', N'$(descr)')
```

Obviously this is rather headache inducing, so it's fortunate that a requirement for literals is rare. If you need to do this many times, you're better off with a variable just for `$` itself:

```
:setvar dollar $
INSERT INTO ABC.TableA(Name, Descr) VALUES ('Payment', N'$(dollar)(1.2)')
```